# VisaIOError while interfacing with SRS instrument

Tags: python

I am trying to interface to SRS 830 and the code I am using is:

```
import visa
import pyvisa
import time
import qcodes as qc
from time import sleep
from qcodes.instrument_drivers.stanford_research.SR830 import SR830

#%% CONNECT TO INSTRUMENT
sr = SR830('lockin', 'GPIB0::8::INSTR')
```

I am getting an error

raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
VisaIOError: ('VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.', "asking 'ISRC?' to ", 'getting lockin_input_config')